# Adding a request variable in a Django template

Tags: javascript, django, forms, django-forms, django-templates

I am currently uploading a file to the server in Django as follows (For some unrelated reasons, I cannot use models for this form):

```
<div class="input-group" style="padding-top: 10px">
    <div><input class="form-control" id="filename" value="Select a ZIP file to upload..." disabled></div>
    <div class="input-group-btn"><input type="button" id="get_file" class="btn btn-primary" value="Browse"
                                                    style="margin-right: 3px;margin-left: 3px"></div>
    <div class="input-group-btn"><input type="submit" id="upload"
         class="btn btn-success" value="Upload" style="display: none"></div>
   <input type="file" id="upload_file" name="upload_file" accept=".zip">
</div>
```

And then I some JavaScript as:

```
document.getElementById('get_file').onclick = function() {
     document.getElementById('upload_file').click();
};

$('input[type=file]').change(function (e) {
     document.getElementById('filename').value = ($(this).val());
     document.getElementById('upload').style.display = "inline"
});

document.getElementById('upload').onclick = function() {
};
```

This works fine and I can upload the file just fine. However, now along with a file, I also want to send a string identifier. I am not sure how I can insert another request parameter on submit from this template?

The Django side looks like:

```
def upload(request):
    """
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['upload_file']:
        # Do things
```

So I need to add another parameter, so that I can do something like: `request.GET.get('identifier')` and this `identifier` key/value is inserted in the template code.

Comment: Hi Luca. I happened to notice on your profile that you prefer to write titles in all-lower-case, presumably for stylistic reasons. Could I trouble you to use sentence case instead? There are a good number of editors on the site, who volunteer their time to tidy things up and to make them as readable as possible, but it would help them (and me) enormously if the amount of new work created can be reduced! Thanks.

Comment: @halfer Of course. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does adding a hidden input inside the form work?

```
<input type="hidden" name="identifier" value="..."/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the `request.GET.get('studyid')` in my view still returns None. I added: `<input type="hidden" name="studyid" value="Test"/>`

Comment: As I was writing this, I realized how stupid i am! It should be `request.POST.get(...)`